# how to preload images with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, preload

For example I have module "menu". This module depends on menu.js, menu.css modules. In menu.css there are some styles with image url. For example there is menu.sprite.png And I have module "home.page". When you click "load menu" button on home page, I want for menu.css and menu.sprite.png to be loaded before showing module "menu". How can I do loading images with webpack? Is there any loader which adds img tag on page and then uses onload event for this image?

Comment: Have you tried webpack image loader? https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader

Comment: this loader is for optimization. I do not need the optimization, I need preload images

Comment: You can just use [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) - so your sprite will be loaded with the script.

Comment: Yes, I can, but browsers have data url size limit, so some images will not be loaded using url-loader